# No drivers for PCI-to-Parallel card due to invalid PID

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, pci, parallel-port

I have a Moschip-based PCI to dual Parallel card, based on the Moschip MCS9815CV chip.
This card looks [exactly like this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815104231) and also same chip as [the Rosewill RC-304](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815166007&cm_re=rosewill_rc-304-_-15-166-007-_-Product).

The back of the card has a sticker: IO-PP210.

Front, printed on the board: NM9735 REV C

Windows 7 x64 refuses to find or load a driver for this card.  I have tried drivers direct from Moschip as well as Rosewill and others.  FYI This card WAS working in Windows XP 32-bit.

I am noticing a an issue: in Device Manager, in the Device Properties section, this card lists the vendor ID as 9710 and the product ID as **1815**.  However, all the drivers that I have found for download have an .INF file that references VID 9710, PID **9815**.

Could this have been a typo when flashing the card's firmware on production?

Suggestions on how to find a driver and/or modify an INF to make this card work in Win7x64?

Comment: change the ID inside the INF and try to install the driver again.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it has a different pid even though it's an identical product?

Comment: I have no idea. I never used this device.